# Assigning macro to buttons with different single arguments

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have a Sub that creates multiple buttons in multiple rows based on values stored on those rows. I have another Sub that I want to be assigned to each of those buttons but with a different argument for each row.

This second sub just selects the sheet whose name are given as argument.

The two subs are the following:

```
Sub GenerateButtons()

  Dim btn As Button
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  
  ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
  
  Dim t As Range
  
  For i = 1 To 78 Step 1
    
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 5))
    
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    
    With btn
      .OnAction = "'GoToSheet " & Sheets("SheetCount").Range("A" & i).Value & "'"
      .Caption = Sheets("SheetCount").Range("A" & i).Value
      .Name = Sheets("SheetCount").Range("A" & i).Value
    End With
  
  Next i
  
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

```
Sub GoToSheet(sheet As String)
    
  Sheets(sheet).Select
    
End Sub
```

When I run the first macro, the buttons and macros are assigned to those buttons, but when I click on one of those Excel prompts an error message saying the macro "MyWorkbook.xlsm'!'GoToSheet Argument1" is not available.

I have all macros enabled and those two macros are stored in a standard module (Module1).

What is wrong with this code? If there's another way to achieve this task (buttons for each row selecting a sheet), I would appreciate to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the values you're adding as parameters to `OnAction` numeric, or text?  It's possible you're missing quotes around the parameter.

Comment: The values on Sheets("SheetCount").Range("A" & i).Value are text, do I need to put it under quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
.OnAction = "'GoToSheet " & Sheets("SheetCount").Range("A" & i).Value & "'"
```

should be

```
.OnAction = "'GoToSheet """ & Sheets("SheetCount").Range("A" & i).Value & """'"
```

http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/06/03/passing-arguments-through-onaction/

Tested:

```vba
Sub GenerateButtons()

  Dim btn As Button, i As Long, t As Range, ws As Worksheet, v
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  ws.Buttons.Delete
  
  For i = 1 To 4
    
    Set t = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5)
    Set btn = ws.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    
    v = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
    With btn
      .OnAction = "'GotoSheet """ & v & """'"
      .Caption = v
      .Name = v
    End With
  
  Next i
End Sub

Sub GotoSheet(s)
    Debug.Print s
End Sub
```

Comment: It's prompting a compile error: variable or procedure expected, not module.

Comment: If you hit Debug when that happens what line is highlighted?

Comment: It shows a compile error and no debug button: https://imgur.com/a/xr06Xaw

Comment: It selects that "Sheets" part of the .OnAction line

Comment: The problem is that I had a module called "Sheets". Now it worked, thanks!

Comment: The code I posted is working for me, but I don't have your exact setup.  Do you have a code module with the same name as one of your worksheets?

Comment: Yes, I think it conflicted with the Sheets VBA object.